# RedirectToAction List<T> Parameter will not be right forwarded to actionmethod

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a action method (FileUpload) which process the uploaded data and forward the use to a new actionmethod. The processed data should be send as parameter to other action method.

```
public RedirectToRouteResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    //datalist contains 3 elements
    List<Data> datalist = Import.ImportCSVFile(
                                   new StreamReader(file.InputStream)).ToList(); 
    return RedirectToAction("EditDataList",
                            new RouteValueDictionary(new { DataList = datalist, 
                                                           bla = "asfd" }));

}
public ViewResult EditDataList(List<Data> DataList=null,String bla="nothing set")
{
    if (DataList == null)
    {
        DataList = base.CreateViewModelContext().DataList.ToList();
    }

    return View(DataList);
}
```

When I'm attached to the debugger in the fileupload action method the datalist contains 3 elements. When i step through to the EditDataList the DataList parameter is initialized and contains 0 elements. The parameter bla is set to asdf which is correct.

Have anyone a idea why I dont recieve the datalist in the EditDataList action method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RedirectToAction` is not simply a call to another action. In fact it goes a full response-request cycle. Here is the description from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

> Returns an HTTP 302 response to the browser, which causes the browser
>   to make a GET request to the specified action.

Is this really the desired behavior? If yes, you might have a hard time sending these files to new action, and better off saving them somewhere and sending just IDs to the other action. If not, you should simply call the other action like a regular method. This is perfectly fine thing to do.

```
return EditDataList(datalist, "asfd");
```

Comment: Thanks, I think i should just simply call the method return EditDataList(datalist, "asfd"); as you suggested. But then I have to change the returntyp of FileUpload, right? But I'm not quite sure which returntyp it should be because setting it to viewresult or actionresult requires a View for FileUpload and my goal is to send the processed data to the EditDataList actionmethod and show the view of EditDataList.

Comment: @Briefkasten, `ActionResult` is your best bet - this is a basic class of all action results, and does not put any restrictions on what is being actually returned.

Comment: Ok, but when setting public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file) and returning return EditDataList(datalist, "asfd"); results in displaying the FileUpload page instead of the EditDataList page.

Comment: @Briefkasten, so you actually do want to make a redirect? Change the url in browser? Because the page content should be the one of `EditDataList` page, but the URL will be of `FileUpload`, true enough

Comment: "so you actually do want to make a redirect? Change the url in browser?" Yes, and send the datalist from the fileupload to the EditDataList actionmethod.

Comment: @Briefkasten,well, hope now you can see it is not possible in that easy way. Redirect is done via GET, which makes it impossible to pass files along with it. Therefore you should opt to storing these files somewhere and sending their IDs to the `RedirectToAction`. However, here is another idea - you can actually have an action with desired URL that accepts `HttpPostedFileBase`, and call `EditDataList` method from it.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand your point. I think I try your last suggestion. :)